# Setting custom cursor via css in winforms WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, css, winforms, webbrowser-control, custom-cursor

I'm using the old WebBrowser control in a winforms app (C#) to display some static html document. So far, I managed to display what I want, react in a custom way to link clicks, show custom rich tooltips etc.

I'm struggling to set custom mouse cursors, though. The Control itself does not support the ctrl.Cursor property, and setting cursors via CSS in the HTML does only work for standard cursors, NOT for custom cursors.

I'm aware of the neccessity to set the engine to latest (see meta tag in head). The question is, how can I point to a .cur / .png file; I tried with relative paths, absolute paths (just for tests), or doesn't the WebBrowser control maybe allow custom cursors at all?

Here's my snippet:

```
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=edge"" />
    <title>Foo</title>
    <style>
    .customcursor {cursor:url('C:\path\to\stuff.cur'), auto !important;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='...' class='customcursor'>Foo</a>
</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: Whats with the double curly brackets in the css?

Comment: Oh, oops, in my original test file there's a string.Format(...) around it. Please ignore those.